# create new column for range price

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a SQL query.

I want to show the product price and also show a price range column. If the price of the product is less than 4, the price range shall be stated as 'Low Price'. If the price is 4 or above but less than 10, price range is stated 'Average price'. If the price is 10 or above, the price range is listed as 'High Price'.

Do you have any ideas on how to define this range column?

The table of prices:

[image]

Comment: Hint:  `CASE` expression.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and edit your question to show the SQL code you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct pp.ProductID , p.Name, pp.UnitPrice ,"PriceRange"=
case 

     WHEN  pp.UnitPrice < 4 THEN 'Low Price'  
     WHEN  pp.UnitPrice >=4 and pp.UnitPrice < 10 THEN 'Average price'  
     WHEN  pp.UnitPrice >=10  THEN 'High Price'  
end
from Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail pp ,Production.Product p 
where pp.ProductID =p.ProductID
order by ProductID
```

Comment: No case matches when UnitPrice = 10; also consider adding an ELSE clause to the case statement, and using `as PriceRange` after the statement instead of "PriceRange"= before it. More importantly, you probably want a group by (and ?average) rather than a distinct.

Comment: Avoid old style `from Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail pp ,Production.Product p 
where pp.ProductID =p.ProductID` and use ANSI style `from Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail pp INNER JOIN Production.Product p 
ON pp.ProductID =p.ProductID`